# No me funciona el método PUT en Laravel 6.3

Tags: laravel, formularios, laravel-blade, blade, laravelcollective

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que funcione con roles. Resulta que tengo una ruta para actualizar los permisos del nuevo rol y lo tengo con el método PUT.
Pero me lanza el siguiente error.
Cuando cambio el metodo PUT por el metodo POST ya el error no me sale pero no me guarda la información en la base de datos. Entonces no entiendo bien donde esta el error pues las rutas estan declaradas como PUT

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE.

Estas son las rutas definidas.

```
Route::post('roles/store', 'RolController@store')->name('roles.store')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.create');

    Route::get('roles', 'RolController@index')->name('roles.index')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.index');

    Route::get('roles/create', 'RolController@create')->name('roles.create')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.create');

    Route::put('roles/{role}', 'RolController@update')->name('roles.update')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.edit');

   Route::get('roles/{role}', 'RolController@show')->name('roles.show')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.show');

   Route::delete('roles/{role}', 'RolController@destroy')->name('roles.destroy')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.destroy');


    Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'RolController@edit')->name('roles.edit')
            ->middleware('permission:roles.edit');
```

Este es el controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Role;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RolController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::paginate();

        return view('roles.index', compact('roles'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $permissions = Permission::get();
        return view('roles.create', compact('permissions'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $role = Role::create($request->all());

         //Actualizar permisos de usuario
        $role->permissions()->sync($request->get('permissions'));

        return redirect()->route('roles.edit',$role->id)
        ->with('info','Role guardado con éxito');
    }



        /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Role $role)
    {
        return view('roles.show', compact('role'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Role $role)
    {
        $permissions = Permission::get();
        return view('roles.edit', compact('role', 'permissions'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    {

        //Actualizar datos de usuario
        $role->update($request->all());

        //Actualizar permisos de usuario
        $role->permissions()->sync($request->get('permissions'));

        return redirect()->route('roles.edit',$role->id)
        ->with('info','Rol actualizado con éxito');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Role $role)
    {
       $role->delete();
       return back()->with('info','Rol eliminado con éxito');

    }
}
```

Así se ve en la vista Blade

```
  @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  Role
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                {!!Form::model($role, ['route'=>['roles.update',$role->id,
                'method' => 'PUT']])!!}
                 @csrf



                   @include('roles.partials.form')

                {!!Form::close()!!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection


<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('name', 'Nombre del usuario')}}
    {{Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('slug', 'URL Amigable')}}
       {{Form::text('slug',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('description', 'Descripción')}}
       {{Form::textarea('description',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Permiso Especial</h3>
<div class="form-group">
       <label>{{Form::radio('special','all-access')}} Acceso Total</label>
       <label>{{Form::radio('special','no-access')}}  Ningun Acceso</label>


</div>

<hr>

<h3>Lista de Permisos</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
       <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
          <li>
            <label>
                {{Form::checkbox('permission[]',$permission->id,null)}}
                {{$permission->name}}
                <em>({{$permission->description ? :'Sin descripción'}})</em>

            </label>

          </li>

        @endforeach
       </ul>

    </div>


<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::submit('Guardar',['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary'])}}
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se por que razon en el request me sale el metodo POST y en la consulta el metodo PUT
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando abres el form, no debes poner la llave `'method'` dentro de la llave `'route'`:

```
{!! Form::model($role, [
    'route' => ['roles.update', $role->id, 'method' => 'PUT']
]) !!}
```

En cambio, `'route'` y `'method'` deben ser dos llaves distintas:

```
{!! Form::model($role, [
    'route' => ['roles.update', $role->id], 
    'method' => 'PUT'
]) !!}
```

Laravel Collective Docs:
[Opening A Form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#opening-a-form)
[Form Model Binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#form-model-binding)

---

**UPDATE**
Agregando manualmente el campo oculto `_method`:

```
{!! Form::model($role, ['route' => ['roles.update', $role->id]]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'put') !!}
    @csrf
    @include('roles.partials.form')
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Me sigue lanzando el mismo error

Comment: Lo que veo raro en la imagen del error, es que la url muestra `?method=PUT`, y debería ser `?_method=PUT`, pues lo acabo de probar y así me aparece a mí y funciona (aunque estoy usando una versión anterior). Te sugiero que pruebes agregarlo manualmente como un input oculto `{!! Form::hidden('_method', 'put') !!}` y lo quites de de la etiqueta `Form`

Comment: Me di cuenta de un detalle en el request me sale el metodo POST y en la consulta el método PUT. Subi una imagen

Comment: Sí, lo del request está bien "Dado que los formularios HTML solo admiten POST y GET, los métodos PUT y DELETE serán falsificados al agregar automáticamente un campo oculto _method a su formulario.". Lo que no está funcionando es el campo oculto. Por eso te decía que pruebes agregarlo manualmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya funciono

Comment: Genial. Es raro que no funcione como debería, parece un bug en la librería. Suerte que se puede hacer artesanalmente. Saludos.